# If the projectile that strikes the inclined plane is perpendicular to the surface then why the velocity of the projectile along the plane is zero

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile

If the projectile that strikes the inclined plane is perpendicular to the surface then why the velocity of the projectile along the plane is zero (down to up projectile in incline plane)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no component of velocity along the plane

Let's say you drop a ball from a building and it hits perpendicularly ,is there any horizontal motion ?no.

This also applies for the plane ,if it hits perpendicularly there is no component of velocity along the plane it hits perpendicularly.